# Added a "Japan" tag

Tags: discussion

I added a tag for bicycling in Japan: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/japan

This follows the same for the UK: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk

I'm not sure how many of these regional geographic tags we need. Perhaps we should just let usage drive it, even though I think we should add a NZ tag for Criggie. :)

I should note that the "regional" tag (https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk+regional) only points to UK regional questions.

Should we delete "regional" and just let people use specific geographic tags? I don't think that we should either pre-populate geographic areas, but just see where demand drives it. The only significant geographic area that I would see emerging in the current would be "Netherlands" given the peculiarity of their bicycle culture.

Answer (score 1):

I think keeping a *regional* tag serves two purposes:

- Regions we haven't thought of (yet) or don't attract enough traffic to be worth it (hypothetically, a question relating to Canada and the US could be tagged [north-america] by analogy with [europe])
- Differences between regions -- something like "How do lighting regulations vary around the world" would max out on tags even if we had one per continent.

That's not to say it's working well at the moment though